# Clone cosmos Db - EnableDataTransfer is not enabled for this account

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to follow this document to clone my cosmosdb container https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-container-copy

When I ran create container job copy command. I have this error[image]

I try to find it on azure documents but nowhere it talk about this errors. At first I think it is about setting  of the cosmos account  but I have a look at Json template for cosmos, there is no property EnableDataTransfer or something similar.
I also confirm that I have write data access to that cosmos account.
Could anyone help please. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a subscription-level issue; not a programming question

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have skipped over this step right there from that docs page to register first for the feature.

To get started using container copy jobs, register for "Intra-account offline container copy (Cassandra & SQL)" preview from the '[Preview Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/access-previews)' list in the Azure portal. Once the registration is complete, the preview will be effective for all Cassandra and API for NoSQL accounts in the subscription.